# Google Webmaster tool showing 500/502 Error on Working pages

Tags: nginx, 500-error, google-webmaster-tools

My website is developed on python and the server is Nginx. The reports in google webmaster tools show some **5xx**(500/502) errors but when I check these URLs on my python script and online websites, the response is 200. What can be the possible reason for this and how do I handle this situation

following links is from the webmaster report:
http://www.getmecab.com/one-way/chandigarh/dehradun

Answer (score 1):

Read through your application logs and web server logs. Those will have information on the 500 error. If they don't, increase log verbosity.